# Printing out a string from a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, printf

I'm learning C programming and I'm having some issues to print a name that i store in a char array.

```
char nameArr[125];
for (int i = 0; i < 125; i++)
{
    if (nameArr[i] != "\0")
    {
        printf(nameArr[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        i = 125;
    }
}
```

This is my code in which I try to print out a name like "Joe Doe" that I already stored in the char array, but I get some errors in the compiler when I run this.
If I'm not suppose to do like this, how can I print out just the name and not all the 125 slots of the array?

Comment: `printf(nameArr[i]` do see something amiss here?

Comment: What's the colon (`:`) doing in the for loop header?

Comment: Opps yes, I see it. I will edit it

Comment: Inquiring about basic syntax rules always help.

Comment: @FelixPalmen fixed it. I just did a typo

Comment: And now you have a serious bug, you treat `nameArr[i]` as the *format string* for `printf()`.

Comment: printf is a bit strange.  it's first argument is a string with formatting and placeholders for the data you want to print, subsequent arguments give the data to fill the placeholders.  try `printf("%c", nameArr[i]);`.  You can also put a `printf("\n");` after the loop just to start a new line after your output.

Comment: @FelixPalmen how am I suppose to get the char for the array then and print it if I can't do it like that?

Comment: Is `nameArr` a *null-terminated byte string*? I.e. does it contain a proper string? Then just print it using the `"%s"` format: `printf("%s\n", nameArr)`. No need for the loop.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b ah okay. I remember now how it works in C

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude does that mean that he printf understands where the string ends? I have checked inside the array and I can se that it contains both the "\n" and a "\0" char and after that its just null.

Comment: As for the errors you get, when asking a question about build errors, *include the actual errors in the question!*. Copy them, as text and in full and complete, then paste it into the question body. A hint though: `nameArr[i]` is a single character, or type `char`. `"\0"` is a *string* of type `char [2]` (but will decay to `char *` for the comparison). You can't really compare a `char` with a `char *`.

Comment: It seems you could need [a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: instead of this articial `i = 125;` just use *`break`*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala or better use the actually correct loop condition (byte at current position is non-`0`).

Comment: Copy/paste the code you actually tested.  Anything else, like manually transcribing it directly from a textbook or homework, is a waste of everybody's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `nameArr` already contains a *string*, which is defined as a sequence of characters ending with `0`, the **obvious** solution is to do

```
printf("%s", nameArr);
```

or

```
puts(nameArr); // appends newline automatically
```

---

If your question is how you would do this by hand, it would look something like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; nameArr[i]; ++i)
{
    putchar(nameArr[i]);
    // or printf("%c", nameArr[i]);
}
```

`nameArr[i]` evaluates as true as long as this **isn't** a `0` byte. Also, **always** use `size_t` for array indices. `int` is not guaranteed to hold any size an object in C can have.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Think I understand now